# Can a positive $W$ boson and negative $W$ boson exchange a lepton, and release a charged lepton antilepton pair or neutrino antineutrino pair?

Tags: forces, feynman-diagrams, neutrinos, weak-interaction, leptons

Would it be possible for two passing $W$ bosons with opposing charge to either release a neutrino and become the corresponding charged lepton and charged antilepton, or release a charged lepton, and become the corresponding neutrino and antineutrino? Like a force seen in the diagram

[image: Diagram of a positive W boson and negative W boson exchanging a lepton]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The processes $W^+ W^+ \to \ell^+ \ell^-$ and $W^+ W^+ \to \nu_\ell \bar{\nu}_\ell$ exist. There are also additional tree level graphs with $Z^0$ and Higgs exchange in the s-channel (H-exchange only for charged leptons in the final state). But what is your problem?

Comment: @Hyperon except they are within virtual interactions. there are no real incoming particles W as the W decay very fast in a lot of particles https://cds.cern.ch/record/2725815?ln=en

Comment: @ anna v: Yes, of course. Known as as "vector boson fusion" (ATLAS, etc.).

Comment: @Hyperon I was mainly just wanting to know if this was possible, or if there was a reason this didn’t happen. I wasn’t sure if it broke conservation of energy or something similar. So, sorry if I wasted your time

Comment: @zion does math weird : Don't worry, that's the purpose of PSE!